# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scripts')

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, npm, node-modules

Версия node v20.9.0, npm 10.1.0

При запуске npm run watch выдаёт следующую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

package.json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').
mix.scripts([
    'public/test/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
    'public/test/retina-1.1.0.min.js',
    'public/test/jquery.cookie.js',
    'public/test/styleswitch.js',
    'public/test/jquery.smartmenus.min.js',
    'public/test/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js',
    'public/test/owl.carousel.min.js',
    'public/test/jflickrfeed.js',
    'public/test/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    'public/test/jquery.isotope.min.js',
    'public/test/swipe.js',
    'public/test/jquery.sticky.js',
    'public/test/main.js',  
],  
    'public/js/all.js').mix.scripts([
    'public/test/fileinput.min.js',
    'public/test/inputmask.js',
    'public/test/jquery.inputmask.js',
    'public/test/flash_message.js',
    'public/test/select2.min.js',
    'public/test/ru.js',
    'public/test/text_area_counter.js',
    'public/test/text_area_counter.js',
    'public/test/file_input.js',
 ], 'public/js/libs.js');
```

Переустановка webpack-cli и очистка кэша npm (npm cache clean --force) не помогли. Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: в конце 4той строки не нужна точка

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос на английской версии сайта
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472335/10758813